# Rewrite Rule for encoded param names

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-config

I have a Condition Working :

```
ex: 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)paramname=value$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com? [R=301]
```

But when the paramname is encoded in browser URL like: `paramnam%65=value`, the redirect not working.

Do we have a solution for this..
Please assist if anyone knows.

Comment: Not sure if there is a proper way to deal with this, other than listing the “alternatives” for every single character, i.e. having every single one expressed in the form `(e|%65)`.

Comment: You can apply URL decoding in the context of a RewriteMap, but that requires access to the central server configuration, and can not be done using .htaccess. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int

Comment: I  think the one you said is the solutoin. Thank you CBroe....